# When the pageSize of Antd Pagination was not setted in multiples of 10 (like 5 or 6,7,8) , "size/page" not show?

Tags: pagination, antd

I change the pageSize of Antd Pagination into 15, and found the pageSize content just show "15", not "15/page".

But the pageSize select options is ["10/page","20/page","30/page"……], and I can't use API "pageSizeOptions" to fix it, because my "pageSize" is a dynamic number.

Does any one meet this problem? Pls give me some suggestions.

Antd version 3.12.1

Answer (score 4):

In Antd, `Pagination` component needs three props(`pageSize`, `current` and `total`) to work as you want.

As you know `pageSize` has default value 10 but values of rest props are not provided by you. You have to provide those details as props in `Pagination` component.

For more details please read this https://ant.design/components/pagination/

Comment: I suppose “pageSize ” is a fixed number，has a init value like 10.
But when I set the init value to 15, the UI box  just show  "15", not "15/page".
That's the question.

Comment: @coyhom You have to provide `total` (No. of total items) to `Pagination` component as a props. Please read this  https://ant.design/components/pagination/